# Snake game in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to make a small IA32 game(AT&T), the problem I'm facing at the moment is I don't know how/where to store the snakes body and the "apples" to be able to check for collisions. 
The snakes size is constantly increasing so the container should be dynamically allocated?

In a high level language I'd use a 2d vector/array/linked list or similar to store the coordinates and then compare after a move is made.

any suggestions are welcome.

(Looked at similar questions but didn't get my question answered)

Comment: How about you just set aside a certain amount of static memory and let that determine the snake's maximum length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snake can't be longer than the field, so allocate the suitable amount of memory statically or dynamically - it is up to you.